# Using Hibernate3 and Java 17 in Wildfly 28/30

Tags: wildfly, java-17, hibernate3, wildfly-28

I would like to know if anyone has been successful in using Hibernate3 and Java 17 with Wildfly 28 or 30 please? I have read posts which mention adding an additional folder to the modules directory and placing all the hibernate related jars in there. Also added in jboss-deployment-structure.xml as well as change the provider module in persistence.xml to use this new module.

This,  so far has not been successful. Can anyone please give their assistance/input relating to the above please?

1. Added a module in the modules directory of wildfly under org/hibernate/3. Have the relevant jars called in the module.xml present in the '3' directory.
2. Added jboss-deployment-structure.xml under META-INF of .ear file
3. Changed persistence.xml to have

My jboss-deployment-structure has the exclusions tag with modules "org.hibernate" slot="main", "org.hibernate.validator" slot="main"

Comment: Why are you trying to upgrade only part of the system?  Hibernate 3 was released in 2005 and JBoss 5.1.0 in 2009.  You're dealing with prehistoric software.  You aren't going to be able to pick and choose which parts you want to keep and which parts you want to upgrade.  You need to look at a full upgrade or keep running with software that hasn't been supported in over a decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work. Hibernate 3 does not support Jakarta Persistence 3.1 which is part of Jakarta EE 10. Both WildFly 28 and 30 are Jakarta EE 10 containers.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you advise what would be the best way to approach this as the current running application  is using hibernate 3 and running within JBOSS 5.1.0.GA.

Comment: If you're running on JBoss 5, then you'd have to migrate your full application to Jakarta EE 10. You could try first migrating to WildFly 26.1.3.Final which is the last Jakarta EE 8 version of WildFly. Then look at migrating to WildFly 30 and Jakarta EE 10.

Comment: Hi @James R. Perkins

Please advise that if I use Wildfly 26.1.3. Final as you stated above, can i leave the application with Hibernate 3? If yes, please advise if you have any reading material or guides which I can use to do this please?

Comment: I would guess not, but I honestly don’t know.